# SimpleButton(getChildByName(button_name)) returns null

Tags: actionscript-3

I just started learning AS3 and I'm stuck.

I'm trying to get the instance names of some buttons from an XML file and then make those buttons disapear, but there is a problem. When I try to locate the buttons, the getChildByName
method I use returns null.

Here is my code:

```
for (var i:int = 1; i < countries.item.length(); i++) {
 var button_name:String = countries.item[i].Name.toString();
 trace(button_name);
 var button1:SimpleButton = SimpleButton(getChildByName(button_name));
 trace(button1);
 button1.visible=false;
}
```

As you see, I check if I get the instance names and **trace(button_name)** works fine. 

Now, **trace(button1)** on the other hand returns null and I don't understand why. 
Any suggestions please?

Comment: Are the buttons added to 'this' (to the display object that the above script is in)? Do they actually have instance names? Because that's where you are looking for them.

Comment: Yes every button has an instance name. When I try, for example, **var button1:SimpleButton=SimpleButton(getChildByName("Greece"));**, everything works fine.

Comment: And is "Greece" something you are getting from trace(button_name) as well?

Comment: Yes. The names I get from the XML file are exactly the same as those in my swf file. I made that mistake before and this time I made sure they are the same.

Comment: Wow... That's a weird issue. Can you show the full trace output of the above code?

Comment: Ablania
null
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at geo_cs5_Scene1_fla::MainTimeline/frame2()
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
 at geo_cs5_Scene1_fla::MainTimeline/clickHandler1()

Comment: Are you sure it is not "Albania" in the instance name field? You put "Ablania" in the XML? (or backwards, of course)

Comment: Wow... I'm embarrassed! Thanks! I really couldn't see that!